# ASP.NET Telerik, Grid inside of RadMultiPage

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik

So I am building a page with a radtapstrip and radmultiview and cannot get my grid to load. The tabstrip works fine and loads on my page but the page is empty, just the tabs show up.  I need to the grid to load when I click on the tab.

```
<telerik:radtabstrip ID="RadTabStrip1" runat="server" Skin="Windows7" MultiPageID="RadMultiPage1" SelectedIndex="0" >
<Tabs>
    <telerik:RadTab Text="A" runat="server" PageViewID="Pageview1" />
    <telerik:RadTab Text="B" runat="server" PageViewID="Pageview2"/>
</Tabs>
</telerik:radtabstrip>

<telerik:RadMultiPage id="RadMultiPage1" runat="server" SelectedIndex="0">

<telerik:RadPageView id="Pageview1" runat="server">

  <cc2:AdminGrid ID="AdminGrid" runat="server" />

</telerik:RadPageView>
<telerik:RadPageView id="Pageview2" runat="server" >

  <cc2:AdminBGrid ID="AdminBGrid" runat="server" />

</telerik:RadPageView>
</telerik:RadMultiPage>
```

As you can probably guess I have my grids on different pages, AdminGrid.vb and AdminBGrid.vb.

Comment: "AdminGrid" and "AdminBGrid" is user control?

Comment: Yes, they are. The actual data for the grid gets loaded on those pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of a shot in the dark, but:

- ensure you provide data to your grids in their OnNeedDataSource event
- ensure there are no errors, especially if you are using AJAX it is possible that some server error gets trapped as a JS error
- ensure that there is actually data in the data source. Use a standard gridView for test
- simplify the grids as much as possible in case additional code is causing the problem. The process of elimination should show you the culprit if this is the case
- Look into loading the pageView and its contents dynamically because when the control is generated it is sure to data bind itself: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/tabstrip/examples/multipage/dynamic-pageview-creation/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: Yes, what actually happened is my databind was not correct. After fixing it my tabs load correctly.